# Why/how `gem fetch -s $source` differs from Bundler's `source` statement?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a Bundler setup, where a gem is downloaded from a private source (repository), which is authenticated via an environment variable.

This is the gem preparation workflow:

```sh
$ export MYKEY=key

$ cat >> Gemfile <<EOF
source "https://private.repository.com/" do
  gem 'mygem'
end
EOF

$ bundle package
```

This will fetch all the gems of the Gemfile, and store them under `vendor/cache`; this includes the gem `mygem`.

I wanted to this directly via the `gem` tool, without Bundler. However, when I run:

```sh
$ export MYKEY=key

$ gem fetch --clear-sources -s "https://private.repository.com/" mygem
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'mygem' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://private.repository.com/ - bad response Unauthorized 401 (https://private.repository.com/other/stuff)
```

Why and how does this differ? How can I fetch the gem via `gem` tool?

Comment: Did you set up a `~/.gemrc` with the credentials for your private repo? Bundler uses its config mechanism for stashing private source credentials, which is separate from what `gem` uses.

Comment: Took me a while to figure this out :) I've added the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the `gem` command does not use environment variables for authorization; instead, the authentication token is part of the URL:

```sh
$ gem fetch --clear-sources -s "https://token@private.repository.com/" mygem
```

The above will work.